# How to make Solr recognize synonyms with any digits before them? e.g. # Molar as #M (and vice versa)

Tags: solr, lucene

I need Solr to be able to recognize # Molar as #M (and vice versa) when searching as well as # Normal as #N (and vice versa).

I have many documents with 6 Molar or 1 Molar or 0.5 Molar in the name however many times these are written as 6M or 1M or 0.5M. I want Solr to be able to recognize # Molar as #M (and vice versa) when searching, besides there could be more than 1 digit (such as 12M) or as a decimal (such as 0.1M).

Can't figure out how to do this with synonyms or anything else. The Solr version is 6.2.1

Comment: I don't think Solr supports using pattern matching in the synonyms file, so you might need to use a brute force approach and manually add the synonyms for each case (e.g. 6M, 6 Molar). You can probably write a short script in Ruby/Python/PHP to generate the proper synonyms.

Comment: @HectorCorrea is there another way without using synonyms at all?

Comment: Another approach would be to detect the "6 M" at ingest time and normalize it as "6 Molar" as you index it (or vice versa.) Not sure what would be better for you situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably add a [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) to your analyzer for this.

Something like:

```
<analyzer>
  <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
         pattern="(\d+(.\d+)?)M" replacement="$1 Molar"/>
  <tokenizer ...
</analyzer>
```

CharFilters preprocess the input before tokenization happens, so you don't need to worry about the pattern spanning multiple terms (as you would with a with a PatternReplace token filter) or lowercasing in case you are also dealing with molalities.

Comment: That's a good point, but how can I provide "vice versa"? If just put such charFilters one by one the last one just replaces result of the previous one.

Maybe I could use something like `<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+(.\d+)?)\s+Molar" replacement="$1M"/>` on the index analyzer and `<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+(.\d+)?)M" replacement="$1 Molar"/>` on the query analyzer. Can this approach do the trick?

Comment: @through.a.haze - No, that would do the opposite of the trick, you'd be guaranteed to not get any hits on those terms. Use the same charfilter at index and query time. Basically, the goal is: in the query and indexed content, after the charfilter processes them, you will see always see "1 Molar", and never "1M" (or vice versa, if you prefer). If it is already "1 Molar", then there is nothing that needs to be done.

Comment: you are absolutely right and I lacked a few minutes to realize this myself, thanks!